# NavigationContext returning incomplete data

Tags: c#, navigation, uri, windows-phone-8.1

I have a code in which i'm passing email data to another page. The email body may contain HTML.

On the second page, I have observed that when '&' or '#' etc comes into body content (while getting data from `NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue()`), the string breaks & further data is not obtained.

Code on first page to send data:

```cs
string strParameters = string.Empty;

strParameters += "subject=" + objEmail.Subject;
strParameters += "&from=" + objEmail.FromAddress;
strParameters += "&to=";
for (int i = 0; i < objEmail.NumTo; i++)
{
     strParameters += objEmail.GetToAddr(i) + "; ";
}
strParameters += "&cc=";
for (int i = 0; i < objEmail.NumCC; i++)
{
    strParameters += objEmail.GetCcAddr(i) + "; ";
}
strParameters += "&body=" + objEmail.Body;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageReadMail.xaml?" + strParameters, UriKind.Relative));
```

Code on second page to receive data:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string strOriginalString = e.Uri.OriginalString;

    //get data received from navigation service
    string strBody = "";
    string strSubject = "";
    string strTo = "";
    string strCc = "";
    string strFrom = "";
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("body", out strBody);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("subject", out strSubject);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("from", out strFrom);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("to", out strTo);
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("cc", out strCc);
}
```

Here, `strBody` is having incomplete data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The parameters should be Url-encoded**

You should use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` or `Uri.EscapeDataString()` on each parameter of the Uri. Alternatively, you can use `Uri.EscapeUriString()` on the whole Uri.

**There's a limit on the lenght of a Uri**

Perhaps your string is longer and is getting trimmed? Although, I think if it was longer, it will just throw an exception, rather than trimming it, but you should check it out.

**Better pass the whole email object to PageReadMail**

I think it will be easier and safer to just pass the whole email object to the page, rather than converting it to a string and passing it in the Uri.

Just add a static property of type `YourEmailObjectType` to the `PageReadMail` class and set that property before you navigate to the page. Once you've navigated, get the data that for the email from that property, rather than from the navigation Uri.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace characters ('**&**' and '**#**') :

```
strParameters += "&body=" + objEmail.Body.Replace("&", "%26").Replace("#", "%23");
```